# How to make it possible for menu to go over the logo?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my Ruby on Rails Spree application with the Twitter Bootstrap gem installed I have the following code for my header:

```
<body class="<%= body_class %>" id="<%= @body_id || 'default' %>" data-hook="body">

<%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/header' %>
 (...)
</body>
```

Where shared/header looks as follows:

```
<div class="container header">

    <header id="header" data-hook>
        <div class="container">
            <figure id="logo" class="text-center col-md-4" data-hook>
                <%= logo('store/Logo.png') %>
            </figure>
            <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/nav_bar' %>
            <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/main_nav_bar' if store_menu? %>
        </div>
    </header>


</div>
```

The logo is loaded in the `figure` tag.

What I want to do is that the logo will extend down and be part of the background as well. E.g.,

[image: Like this].

How can I accomplish this? Do I need to make it part of the background of the header and body? Or should I use a css background on the whole page? And if so, how can I make that it rescales with the page?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

/edit Generated HTML:

```
<body class="one-col" id="default" data-hook="body">

  <div class="container header">

    <header id="header" data-hook>
        <div class="container">
            <figure id="logo" class="text-center col-md-4" data-hook>
                <a href="/"><img alt="Logo" src="/assets/store/Logo-c0fd8c5c71ef79825dba0315b84bdef5.png" /></a>
            </figure>

  <ul id="nav-bar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-hook>
<li><a href="/account">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
<li id="search-bar" data-hook>
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/products" class="navbar-form" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="Search" type="search" />
</div>
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</li>
  </ul>
            <nav class="col-md-12"><div id="main-nav-bar" class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-nav" data-hook>
<li id="home-link" data-hook><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="shop-link" data-hook><a href="/shop">Products</a></li>
      <li id="about-link" data-hook><a href="/about">About us</a></li>
      <li id="contact-link" data-hook><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-hook>
<li id="link-to-cart" data-hook><a class="cart-info empty" href="/cart"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Cart: (Empty)</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="locale-select" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;" data-hook>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/locale/set" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="mx8tcgWHDqyVslG5Fxvz6N03KRhtVtr9eXYyqDJpEhQ=" /></div><select class="form-control" data-href="/locale/set" id="locale" name="locale"><option selected="selected" value="en">English (US)</option>
<option value="nl-NL">Nederlands (NL)</option></select><noscript>
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
</noscript>
</form></div>
</div>
</nav>
        </div>
    </header>


</div>

  <div class="container row" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-hook>
    <.. MAIN CONTENT>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's easier to help if you post an online demo, or at least post the generated HTML.

Comment: @ralph.m, the question now contains the generated html.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class or modify an existing one (`text-center` or `col-md-4`) of the logo.

Write into it: `margin-bottom:-30px;`. If it works, replace the `30px` value with one which fits.

Comment: Does this resize if you change the size of the window?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide any playground for us to play with your CSS, I am assuming that doing the following thing would solve your issue.
Give `position:absolute;` to `#logo`. Then, make your logo image as big as you like. And adjust other values as required.

Comment: And dus it resize then if you change the size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You could place the logo as a background image on the header div to get this effect: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/geAsp

Using `background-size`, the logo will be able to resize with the height of the div. The only downside is that the logo is now not available as a link in the HTML, but there are workarounds for that.